# Java Bean not being recognised

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

I have created a java bean with the following information:

package: com.mysite

class: Folders

The file is located in ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/com/mysite/Folders.class

and the call is:

```
<jsp:useBean id="folders" scope="session" class="com.mysite.Folders" />
```

Here's the class if it helps it'a just simple because I want to get it up and running before I do anything more complicated.

```
public class Folders implements Serializable {

public Folders(String accountNumber, String folderName, String groupName, ArrayList<String> folderNames, ArrayList<String> groupNames) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.folderName = folderName;
    this.groupName = groupName;
    this.folderNames = folderNames;
    this.groupNames = groupNames;
}

public String getAccountNumber() {
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public String getFolderName() {
    return folderName;
}

public void setFolderName(String folderName) {
    this.folderName = folderName;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFolderNames() {
    return folderNames;
}

public void setFolderNames(ArrayList<String> folderNames) {
    this.folderNames = folderNames;
}

public String getGroupName() {
    return groupName;
}

public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
    this.groupName = groupName;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGroupNames() {
    return groupNames;
}

public void setGroupNames(ArrayList<String> groupNames) {
    this.groupNames = groupNames;
}


private String accountNumber;
private String folderName;
private String groupName;
private ArrayList<String> folderNames;
private ArrayList<String> groupNames;
}
```

with the same results each time.

The error being:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /custom/folders.jsp(13,0) The value for the useBean class attribute com.mysite.Folders is invalid.
```

I've restarted both Tomcat and the server itself and neither have helped.
Any insight to this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be a valid Java Bean, a class must have a no-argument constructor (it can have other constructors as well, but *must* have at least a no-argument one).  Try adding such a constructor to your `Folders` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to include the JAR into your build path, don't you!?

Comment: This is my first time trying this so I'm not sure what you mean. Do I need to have the whole project on the server?

Comment: No, just right click on the project you're deploying, then click "build path" and "configure build path". In the tab "Libraries" (or so) you can add JARs as libraries.

Comment: Ok I did that and am still having the same issue.

Comment: I get this:    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /custom/folders.jsp(13,0) The value for the useBean class attribute folders is invalid.

Comment: Hirthas I think you also need to create no argument constructor for this bean and then try.